# Search Results - Pagination Error

Tags: search, pagination

I'm currently using Magento 1.9.
When i do a search in the search bar, search always returns me a page with all results(even above 900 results,so it's really really slow).
Pagination of results appears but when i click on any page number it simply reshows me all the results...it seems like that pagination doesn't work!
Could this behaviour depend on my installed Magento theme?
Is there a way to programmatically fix this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any custom modules installed that might affect the search? I have a feeling that something loads the product collection before the pagination can add the limits.

Comment: I'm using Search Autocomplete + Search Suggest by Searchanise...could this be the cause?

EDIT : Disabled it and tested, but i'm still getting the problem.

Comment: did you disable it from the admin? or from `app/etc/modules`? Did you also clear the cache after disabling it?

Comment: Yes i did everything you said.

Comment: Other ideas...suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by this extension...uninstalling it made all work correctly!
I recommend to NOT install it.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/category-access-control.html